# problems with getting substrings from strings in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran

so I am doing a project in Fortran and I'm coming across a problem with the strings but it only is opening in functions the same statements work outside of the function namely any line with the variable point
the error is: "error: 'string' argument of 'len' intrinsic ant 1 must be character"
or "error the allocatable object 'point' ar(1) must have an explicit function interface or be declared array"

```
    function valueCheck(point) result(torf)
        implicit none
        logical :: torf
        character (len=:), allocatable:: point
        integer :: c
        print *, len(point)
        torf = .true.
        do c=1, len(point), 1
            if (.not. ((point(c) >= "0") .and. (point(c) <= '9') .or. (point(c) == "+") .or. (point(c) == " ")) ) then
                torf = .false.
                exit
            end if
        end do
    end function valueCheck
```

Comment: Is the incorrect spelling `alocatable` in your real code?

Comment: You also can't reference a substring with `point(c)` instead of `point(c:c)`. So along with the complete example, please clearly show where error messages are pointing to.

Comment: yes it is the correct spelling in the real code

Comment: ```print *, len(point)``` also does not work which I believe gets us to the root of my problem

Comment: @francescalus thanks that at least fixed one of my problems and some how makes the other problem fixed as well ????
```print *, len(point)```

Comment: @francescalus Misread before my first cup of tea this morning - I thought torf was the argument, now see it is the result. Will delete comment